# Laravel - trying to access storage gives forbidden error

Tags: laravel, symlink

On the linux server I have an instance of laravel.
I tried to ssh into the server and run the command:  php artisan link:storage
Nothing happened, there were no errors or responses on the console.

So I tried to create the symlink like so: ln -s storage/app/ public/storage
This creates a symlink but no shortcut folder called 'storage' appears in the public folder like it usually does.

Also when trying to access a resource, I get a forbidden error 403. The path to the resource is
You don't have permission to access *domain-name/public/storage/133/cipla_vitamins_icon.svg* on this server.
When I am expecting: You don't have permission to access *domain-name/storage/133/cipla_vitamins_icon.svg* on this server.

Do I need to fix the symlink or is this an htaccess fix?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check what directory permissions you have in there? make sure its 755 or 777.

Comment: Yup, both of them are 755

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. I had to put an absolute path to both locations for this to work:

ln -s /usr/www/users/ftp_username/storage/app/ /usr/www/users/ftp_username/public/storage

Now its working hooray.